# How to safely restart Scheduled reminders

Tags: scheduled-reminders

Recently scheduled reminders stopped working on a site.

on investigation of error logs I found that one reminder out of several was incrrectly configured. I deleted the reminder. The next time the scheduled reminder job ran, all went well but a backlog of 3 months of event reminders sent at the same time.

I've found a similar error on another site, and have disabled scheduled reminder task while investigating and deleting the incorrectly configured reminder.

before I turn the scheduled reminder task back on, how can I stop the backlog of old reminders from sending?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have made the same mistake myself, more than once - ugh! To avoid emails being sent when a scheduled job needs to catch up on backlog:

1. Switch from [**production to staging**](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/staging-production/) mode
2. Manually execute the schedule reminders job - this will result in an activity being recorded on the participant's contact record, but will not send the email (the desired impact)
3. Switch back to production - the activities recorded on the participant's contact record will prevent schedule reminders being sent for the same events

Hope this helps!

Tamar

Comment: That's marvellous. Thanks Tamar!

Now I've found the next badly configured scheduled reminder. This is going to be a fun afternoon.