# Backlog of scheduled reminders

Tags: civimember, scheduled-reminders

We have a civi install with imported memberships, which have ended between 1 month and two years ago. We would like to start sending out reminders but when we send out sheduled reminders (with repeat option) it looks like it only sends when the exact period is matched.

I would have expected that it would send out mails to all memberships that have ended at least one month ago and then repeat following the settings in the repeat option... Can anyone help me with the logic of this (and send out reminders for these old expired memberships?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem

[How to safely restart Scheduled reminders](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27389/how-to-safely-restart-scheduled-reminders)

And got a really clear and succinct answer.

Comment: thank you very much, but we actually want the reverse.. We do want to send out the reminders even though they are overdue for a long time.
We plan to make groups now and send one-off reminders until we can let the normal procedure kick in again.

Comment: What are the date/status  settings on the reminder?Could you add a screenshot?

Comment: Sorry did not further investigate as we will work around with groups